# UISlider is not smooth on first generation iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, uislider, uitouch

I am developing an iPad application and in my application I have used UISlider and I have tested my app in Ipad1 but it is not responding very smooth. But, the same application is responding very smooth in iPad 2nd gen.

In iPad first gen, every time I move the slider the slider value changed action is called but I'm not doing anything on that function. I am doing all my actions only on touch up inside and touch up outside. It is not working fine because it is not always called. Is there is any way to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Using many UIImageView with partial transparent images or glow/shadow effects on UILabels and similar can slow down the application. It can be anything different from the UISlider which slows down the displaying of the UI.

Otherwise you have made something very CPU intensive in the observer of the UISlider.